# Need to parse a date range location in a field to two SQLStatements

Tags: sql, parsing, netsuite

Have a custom field that contains a date range in the following format:

```
3/16/20 - 2/22/20
```

What I need to do is separate this one line into two different fields, the first selection/range and the second range, so if you take the screenshot I need it to be separated to `3/16/20` for one field and `3/22/20` for the other field.

Currently I have this and something is causing an error randomly and I want to make sure it is not the SQL statement

For the first selection, I use the following:

```
TO_DATE(LTRIM(SUBSTR({custbody_shipwindow}, 1,(INSTR({custbody_shipwindow}, '-')-1))),'mm/dd/yy')
```

For the second selection I use the following:

```
TO_DATE(LTRIM(SUBSTR({custbody_shipwindow},(INSTR({custbody_shipwindow}, '-')+1), LENGTH({custbody_shipwindow}))),'mm/dd/yy')
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM({custbody_shipwindow}),'^[^ -]+'),'MM/DD/YY')

TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM({custbody_shipwindow}),'[^ -]+$'),'MM/DD/YY')
```

or to be safe, but possibly not return the date:

```
TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM({custbody_shipwindow}),'^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}'),'MM/DD/YY')

TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM({custbody_shipwindow}),'[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}$'),'MM/DD/YY')
```

Comment: That works Nathan, thanks! Sorry for the delay in response.